# How to set up and minimize a large system of equations to resolve the individual components

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, functional-style, chemistry

I am trying to set up a system of 400*N equations to deconvolute spectral data for four different compounds.

I monitored 400 different wavelengths in N solvents (3 solvents in this case).  In order to do this, I want to try to minimize the following function:

$A_{\lambda_i, N_i} - (\epsilon_{1 (\lambda_i, N_i)}C_1 + \epsilon_{2 (\lambda_i, N_i)}C_2 + \epsilon_{3 (\lambda_i, N_i)}C_3 + \epsilon_{4 (\lambda_i, N_i)}C_4 = 0 $

Here $A$ is the absorbance of the spectrum I want to deconvolute at specified wavelength ($\lambda$) in solvent ($N$).
$\epsilon$ is the molar extinction coefficient for each different compound that corresponds to the absorbance at the given wavelength and solvent.   Then unknown quantities are $C_1$ to $C_4$

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5gGZ4-SD7-ZdHFveVY5b2J3OTQ&usp=sharing

My data is organized as follows.

Each row has 5 entries and I have 400 rows  one (for each wavelength)
[$A \; \epsilon_1  \; \epsilon_2  \; \epsilon_3  \; \epsilon_4$]

Each solvent has a table organized just like this one.  How do I used mathematica to set up this system of equations and get the error associated with the minimization?  Also, the solution needs to be constrained such that C$_n$ is positive.

Import the data (uploaded on google drive)

```
phosBB = Import["/home/marco/LatexDocs/analytical/uvvis/PHOS_BB.CSV"];
phosMR = Import["/home/marco/LatexDocs/analytical/uvvis/PHOS_MR.CSV"];
phosPT = Import["/home/marco/LatexDocs/analytical/uvvis/PHOS_PT.CSV"];
phosTB = Import["/home/marco/LatexDocs/analytical/uvvis/PHOS_TB.CSV"];
phosUI = Import["/home/marco/LatexDocs/analytical/uvvis/PHOS_UI.CSV"];
```

PreProcess data to get rid of headings:

```
phosBB = Delete[phosBB, 1];
phosMR = Delete[phosMR, 1];
phosPT = Delete[phosPT, 1];
phosTB = Delete[phosTB, 1];
phosUI = Delete[phosUI, 1];
```

Calculate $\epsilon$ from the known solutions (BB-TB):

```
\[Epsilon]PhosBB = phosBB[[All, 2]]/concPhosBB;
\[Epsilon]PhosMR = phosMR[[All, 2]]/concPhosMR;
\[Epsilon]PhosPT = phosPT[[All, 2]]/concPhosPT;
\[Epsilon]PhosTB = phosTB[[All, 2]]/concPhosTB;
```

Setup data table [$A_{unk} \; \epsilon_1  \; \epsilon_2  \; \epsilon_3  \; \epsilon_4$]

```
phosDataTable = 
  Transpose[{phosUI[[All, 1]], \[Epsilon]PhosBB, \[Epsilon]PhosMR, \[Epsilon]PhosPT, \[Epsilon]PhosTB}];
```

Comment: Have you attempted something already with e.g. `FindFit`? Can you show your code?

Comment: It looks like a linear system -- so you can rewrite your equations in matrix form m.x==b and then use `LinearSolve`. m is your data {A, e1, e2, e3, e4}, b is zero and x={c1, c2, c3, c4}.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I'm not sure what mathematica function to use.  The idea is to guess C1-C4 to try to get as close to zero as possible.  There will be some error associated with the calculation because I don't think there is any exact solution.  we just want to get close.

Comment: @bills  I tried using Linear solve where m was {e1,e2,e3,e4}, x = {c1,c2,c3,c4}, b = {A$_{unk}}.  (a rearrangement of the equation i posted above).  There was no exact solution.

Comment: Then try `LeastSquares[m,b]`, which gives a vector `x` that minimizes the `Norm[m.x-b]`.

Comment: @bills how do I get the error associated with the vector LeastSquares returns?

Comment: 400 points is overkill for visible spectra of four components.  If you have access to Harris' Quantitative Chemical Analysis, chapter 18 provides a very thorough explanation and demonstrates the solution using Excel (which turns out to be a MMA one or two liner).

Comment: This is not really a comment on the question so much as a personal appeal to you. Please, try to avoid using the term "deconvolution" to refer to what is basically solving an eigenvalue problem. This confuses people working in other fields and makes us chemists sound mathematically illiterate. One can argue that these two concepts are somehow related, but in practice never have I met a spectroscopist who really knows or cares what "deconvolution" means mathematically or to anyone else. It's my personal goal to persuade those of us who know better to end this abuse of nomenclature!

Comment: @OleksandrR. I have changed the title. Thank you for informing me

Comment: #bobthechemist  thank you for directing me to harris.    Also thanks for showing me how to do the equivalent task in mathematca in a better way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import the data and filenames, cull the datasets of information that is not useful:

```
data = Import /@ FileNames["*.csv"];
filenames = FileNames["*.csv"];
data = data[[All, 2 ;;, {1, 2}]];
ListLinePlot[data, PlotLegends -> filenames]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Looks like PT data was either incorrectly collected or is effectively transparent in the region of interest.  The question currently is missing concentration information, so I will assume each standard is 0.1 M just for pedagogical purposes.  Convert the standard ordinates to molar absorptivities.

```
conc = {0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1};
MapIndexed[(data[[#2, All, 2]] /= #1) &, conc];
```

Now solve the linear system.  Here I'm using the definition of the linear lease squares just for fun.

```
soln = With[{A = data[[1 ;; 4, All, 2]]}, 
  Solve[A.Transpose@A.{c1, c2, c3, c4} == A.data[[5, All, 2]], 
  {c1, c2, c3, c4}]]
(* {{c1 -> 0.059183, c2 -> 0.00586333, c3 -> 0.0171604, c4 -> 0.0195068}} *)
```

(* Note, I would have liked to replace {c1, c2, c3, c4} with the actual filenames but they are not valid mathematica symbols *)

The above expression can also (should also?) be entered as `LeastSquares[Transpose@data[[1 ;; 4, All, 2]], data[[5, All, 2]]]` which yields the same result as a list of coefficients rather than a list of rules.

Create the theoretical curve and compare it to the original

```
theoretical = Transpose[{data[[1, All, 1]], 
   {c1, c2, c3, c4}.data[[1 ;; 4, All, 2]] /. First@soln}];
ListLinePlot[{theoretical, data[[5]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you are interested in parameter errors, then use `LinearModelFit`.

```
lm = LinearModelFit[{Transpose@data[[1 ;; 4, All, 2]], data[[5, All, 2]]}];
lm["ParameterTable"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Not surprisingly, the third variable, corresponding to PT, has the largest error.

Comment: you are right about the PT.  The csv file is still saved on the instrument.  I couldn't get into the room to retrieve the spectrum.  Thank you so much.  I'll repost tomorrow with the PT included so that we can get a good answer.

Comment: I consulted my notebook. The PT solution was clear at at this PH. Could you elaborate on the theoretical and actual fit plot?  I'm not sure I understand what is  being plotted.   Thank you so much.  I'll repost tomorrow with all of the data processed in case you are interested.

Comment: @olliepower the theoretical plot is simulated from the molar absorptivities of the standard compounds and the best fit concentrations of these standards that makes up the final solution.  The other line is the experimental plot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final result if you are interested.

```
 data = Import /@ 
   FileNames["/home/marco/LatexDocs/analytical/uvvis/PHOS_*.CSV"];
data = data[[All, 2 ;;, {1, 2}]];
ListLinePlot[data, PlotLegends -> {"BB", "MR", "PT", "TB", "UI"}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["wavelength (nm)"  , FontSize -> 16], 
   Style["Absorbance", FontSize -> 16]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{400, 750}, {0, 0.9}}]
concBB = 1.6*10^(-5);
concMR = 37.1  * 10^(-5);
concPT = 31.4 * 10^(-5);
concTB =  21.4 * 10^(-5);
conc = {concBB, concMR, concPT, concTB};
MapIndexed[(data[[#2, All, 2]] /= #1) &, conc];
soln = With[{A = data[[1 ;; 4, All, 2]]}, 
   Solve[A.Transpose@A.{c1, c2, c3, c4} == A.data[[5, All, 2]], {c1, 
     c2, c3, c4}]];

theoretical = 
  Transpose[{data[[1, All, 
      1]], {c1, c2, c3, c4}.data[[1 ;; 4, All, 2]] /. First@soln}];
ListLinePlot[{theoretical, data[[5]]}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["wavelength (nm)"  , FontSize -> 16], 
   Style["Absorbance", FontSize -> 16]}]

lm = LinearModelFit[{Transpose@data[[1 ;; 4, All, 2]], 
    data[[5, All, 2]]}];
error1 = Total[(#^2) & @  lm["FitResiduals"]];




data2 = Import /@ 
   FileNames["/home/marco/LatexDocs/analytical/uvvis/CARB_*.CSV"];
data2 = data2[[All, 2 ;;, {1, 2}]];
ListLinePlot[data2, PlotLegends -> {"BB", "MR", "PT", "TB", "UI"}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["wavelength (nm)"  , FontSize -> 16], 
   Style["Absorbance", FontSize -> 16]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{400, 750}, {0, 0.9}}]

MapIndexed[(data2[[#2, All, 2]] /= #1) &, conc];
soln2 = With[{A = data2[[1 ;; 4, All, 2]]}, 
   Solve[A.Transpose@A.{c1, c2, c3, c4} == A.data2[[5, All, 2]], {c1, 
     c2, c3, c4}]];

theoretical = 
  Transpose[{data2[[1, All, 
      1]], {c1, c2, c3, c4}.data2[[1 ;; 4, All, 2]] /. First@soln}];
ListLinePlot[{theoretical, data2[[5]]}]
lm2 = LinearModelFit[{Transpose@data2[[1 ;; 4, All, 2]], 
    data2[[5, All, 2]]}];
error2 = Total[(#^2) & @  lm2["FitResiduals"]];

data3 = Import /@ 
   FileNames["/home/marco/LatexDocs/analytical/uvvis/KHP_*.CSV"];
data3 = data3[[All, 2 ;;, {1, 2}]];
ListLinePlot[data3, PlotLegends -> {"BB", "MR", "PT", "TB", "UI"}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["wavelength (nm)"  , FontSize -> 16], 
   Style["Absorbance", FontSize -> 16]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{400, 750}, {0, 0.9}}]

MapIndexed[(data3[[#2, All, 2]] /= #1) &, conc];
soln3 = With[{A = data3[[1 ;; 4, All, 2]]}, 
   Solve[A.Transpose@A.{c1, c2, c3, c4} == A.data3[[5, All, 2]], {c1, 
     c2, c3, c4}]];

theoretical = 
  Transpose[{data3[[1, All, 
      1]], {c1, c2, c3, c4}.data3[[1 ;; 4, All, 2]] /. First@soln}];
ListLinePlot[{theoretical, data3[[5]]}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["wavelength (nm)"  , FontSize -> 16], 
   Style["Absorbance", FontSize -> 16]}]
lm3 = LinearModelFit[{Transpose@data3[[1 ;; 4, All, 2]], 
    data3[[5, All, 2]]}];
error3 = Total[(#^2) & @  lm3["FitResiduals"]];

dataSummary = {c1, c2, c3, c4} /. {soln, soln2, soln3}
errorSummary = {error1, error2, error3}
```

Mean Concentration Molar

```
{{0.000469681, 0.00678397, 0.0169567, 0.0012554}}
```

Plots:  each  set of three corresponds to: (spectrum, theoretical, plot of residuals)
[image: In Phosphate Buffer]
[image: Theoretical Comparison Phosphate]
[image: Plot of Residuals Phosphate]

[image: In Carbonate Buffer]
[image: Carbonate Theoretical]
[image: Carbonate Error]

[image: In KHP buffer]
[image: KHP theoretical]
[image: KHP error]

Comment: @bobthechemist  I have updated the final result if you are interested.  Is there any reason why the theoretical plot looks so good for the first plot and so bad for the rest of them?  Its pretty odd that there is an apparent structure to the residuals as well.